# android phonegap database connection

Tags: android, jquery, html, database, cordova

I want to use this html and make a database connection to add these things. But I don't really know what to use or how to do it. Can you help me?

```
    <html>
      <head>
    <title>Ingredient</title>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/receta.min.css" />
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/receta.css" />
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.1.1/jquery.mobile-1.1.1.min.js"></script>
      <script src="js/recetas.js">  </script>  

</head>
<div>
<h1>RECETA</h1>
<label for="receta">Nombre Receta:</label><br>
<input type="text" name="receta" value="" maxlength="20" /><br>
</div>
<CENTER>
<body>

      <label>Instrucciones</label>
      <textarea style="width: 300px; height: 150px">

    </textarea>

     <label>Ingredientes</label>
     <ul style="width: 300px; height: 150px">
    <ul>

    </ul>

    <select onchange="selectIngredient(this);">
     <option value="Cheese">Cheese</option>
     <option value="Olives">Olives</option>
     <option value="Pepperoni">Pepperoni</option>
     <option value="Milk">Milk</option>
    </select>

<li style="width: 300px; height: 150px">
<button>GUARDAR</button>
<li><a href="consultas.html" data-transition="none" rel="external">CONSULTAR</a></li>
</body>
</center>
</html>
```

Here is the function of ingredients I use to make the list in the html:

```
function selectIngredient(select)
    { 
      var $ul = $(select).closest('.ui-select').prev('ul');
console.log($ul[0])
  if ($ul.find('input[value=' + $(select).val() + ']').length == 0) {
    console.log('s')
        $ul.append('<li onclick="$(this).remove();">' +
          '<input type="hidden" name="ingredients[]" value="' + 
          $(select).val() + '" /> ' +
          $(select).find('option:selected').text() + '</li>');
  }
    }
```

I could put an image but i need more reputation please help.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You don't want to make a direct database connection from your app.  If you were able to do so, you would potentially expose your database connection credentials to the entire world. Certainly this is not desirable.

What you need to do is put a web service in place which your app calls.  The web service would then make the database interactions.